# Keep wildcard in string when parsing

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'd like to find headings and give them an `id` attribute. For example, I might want to add `id="my-new-id"` to `<h2>`or something like `<h2 class="class-1 class-2">`. The parser method looks like this:

```
def parse_toc(text)
  p = []
  text.split("\n").each do |line|
    if line.match(/\<h2.*?\>/)
      # need to add id
    end
    p.push line
  end
  return p.join("\n")
end
```

I have trouble keeping wildcards as part of the string. How can I keep a wildcard in a string while changing what surrounds it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
puts '<h2>'.gsub(/<h2/, '\& id="my-new-id"')
# <h2 id="my-new-id">
puts '<h2 class="class-1 class-2">'.gsub(/<h2/, '\& id="my-new-id"')
# <h2 id="my-new-id" class="class-1 class-2">
```

BTW, using regular expression to parse/modify html/xml is a bad idea. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2225682).

Comment: Great advice, @falsetru! I'm now using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), and it makes parsing and modifying HTML super easy.